# FTT Features to use after time-domain is transformed to frequency-domain

Tags: fourier-transform, machine-learning, python, fast-fourier-transform, data-mining

Please forgive the question if it sounds trivial/naive, I am from computer science background, not electrical/computer engineering.

I work with GPS trajectory dataset for classification. Data was collected at sampling rate of 1-second per sample.

***time-domain:***

Currently, I considered working with time-domain features only, so I extracted two point-level features:

- `speed:` (rate of distance between consecutive locations with time), and
- `acceleration:` (rate of speed with time).

I then divided each user's trip into fixed-length segments of 100 time steps (100 data points per segment). I finally calculated 11 statistics of each feature (`min, max, mean, median, st-dev, etc`) in the fixed-length segment, making a total of 22 features per segment. This I used to train a classifier (decision tree) for classification.

***frequency-domain:***

But I wanted to try combination of time-and-frequency features in building my model, to see the impact, so using fast Fourier transform, I proceeded in the following way:

1. Take the original 2-featured segments (the 100 fixed data point segments).
2. Use `scipy.fft.fft` to obtain the corresponding frequency spectrum of each feature, thus:

   ```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.fft import fft
    N = 100  # number of samples in a segment
    T = 1    # sample spacing ( 1 second)

    def fft_transform(data):
        """
          compute the FFT of each segment's feature in features's dimension
        """
        fourier = fft(data, axis=2)
        magnitude = np.abs(fourier)

        return magnitude
   ```

   The figure below illustrates an example input in time and frequency domains.
3. Take only the positive frequencies values of the `FFT` (since `FFT` of real-valued input is symmetric).
4. Add the `frequency-domain` values of each feature to its `time-domain`. The result is `11 time-domain` features for `speed` (similarly `acceleration`) and `50 frequncy-domain` features for `speed` (similarly `acceleration`). Total: `122 features` per input.

[image]

The new results obtained yielded significant negative impact on the overall model performance, evaluated on the usual metrics (`precision, recall, f1`).

In the next round of experiment, I would like to  consider significant `FFT` descriptors to add as frequency features instead of using the whole `FFT` values as explained above. I initially thought of computing same feature statistics as I did for the `time-domain`, but was advised that wouldn't make a good features for `FFT` spectrum (that doing so may also lead to discard of important features/pattern).

I can testify to that, as the results I obtained doing so even worsen the model performance. Some classes never get correctly predicted even for 1 sample.

That said, I would like to have your advise regarding:

- What constitute a good `FFT` descriptors to select and add to `time-domain` instead the similar statistics as used for time features?
- Any pointer to the code (python), for your suggestion considering my script above?